# nftables ip set multiple tables

Tags: linux, nftables

**Use case:** I have a home router using iptables today. I'm researching converting over to nftables, as it looks to be much more manageable for a lot of rules.

One thing I have setup today under iptables is a 'country-block' ipset which contains country CIDR blocks that covers the majority of random port probe/hack attempts. Unfortunately nftables can't use my existing ipsets directly, but it was fairly straightforward to convert it to an nftables ip set.

**Problem:** To avoid having one single massive nftables file, I chose to separate my 'country-block' set into a separate file. nftables makes it easy to include other files, so this seems to be well within the intended behavior for nftables. I've defined my country-block as so:

```
table ip country-block {
  set country-block {
    type ipv4_addr;
    flags interval;
    elements = { /* CIDR blocks here */ }
  }
}
```

This loads fine. Now I want to use it in my firewall filters. I have a table defined in my main config file 'table inet filter'. Here I want to add the rule:

```
ip saddr @country-block drop
```

Following all my google searching for answers, this is the only way I've found for referencing ip sets. Unfortunately, this throws the error:

```
Error: Could not process rule: Set 'country-block' does not exist
```

I tried referencing "country-block@country-block" hoping it might resolve to the country-block namespace I created, but that doesn't work:

```
Error: syntax error, unexpected drop
   ip saddr country-block@country-block drop
                                        ^^^^
```

Does anyone know of a way to reference a set that is in a different table? I'd hate to have to collapse all of my sets into my single 'filter' table and maintain them all in a single file - what an ugly mess that would be.

ps. I tried to tag this 'nftables', but apparently it's a new tag and I don't have the rep required to create a new tag. Can some kind person with the required rep please tag this appropriately?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I received a response from the nftables developers after asking on their mail list. The short answer is that referencing sets in another table is not possible.

However, I was at least able to store my sets in a separate file and bring them in via an @include. This makes my ipsets more manageable instead of having to put them all into a single massive configuration file. The syntax is like so:

```
# nftables.conf
include "/etc/nftables.country-block"
table inet filter {
  set country-block {
    type ipv4_addr; flags interval;
    elements = $country_block_list
  }
}

# nftables.country-block
define country_block_list = {
          # comma-separated CIDR blocks here
    }
```

But it's worth noting that as of this writing (2016-12-21), this requires an nft command-line utility built from the latest source code of nftables, as the most current release available at this time (nftables v0.6) will throw an error with the above configuration. nftables has a [pretty good wiki](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Building_and_installing_nftables_from_sources) outlining how to build and install from source, although I don't expect that will be necessary a few months from now once a new version is released and makes its way out into all the various distros.